# Need help limiting a join in Transact-sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, sql-server-2000

I'm somewhat new to SQL and need help with query syntax.

My issue involves 2 tables within a larger multi-table join under Transact-SQL (MS SQL Server 2000 Query Analyzer)

I have ACCOUNTS and LOGINS, which are joined on 2 fields: Site & Subset.
Both tables may have multiple rows for each Site/Subset combination.

> ```
> ACCOUNTS:                                 | LOGINS:
>   SITE    SUBSET  FIELD   FIELD   FIELD   |   SITE    SUBSET  USERID  PASSWD
>   alpha   bravo   blah    blah    blah    |   alpha   bravo   foo     bar
>   alpha   charlie blah    blah    blah    |   alpha   bravo   bar     foo
>   alpha   charlie bleh    bleh    blue    |   alpha   charlie id      ego
>   delta   bravo   blah    blah    blah    |   delta   bravo   john    welcome
>   delta   foxtrot blah    blah    blah    |   delta   bravo   jane    welcome
>                                           |   delta   bravo   ken     welcome
>                                           |   delta   bravo   barbara welcome
> ```

I want to select all rows in ACCOUNTS which have LOGIN entries, *but only **1** login per account.*

> ```
> DESIRED RESULT:
>   SITE    SUBSET  FIELD   FIELD   FIELD   USERID  PASSWD
>   alpha   bravo   blah    blah    blah    foo     bar
>   alpha   charlie blah    blah    blah    id      ego
>   alpha   charlie bleh    bleh    blue    id      ego
>   delta   bravo   blah    blah    blah    jane    welcome
> ```

I don't really care *which* row from the login table I get, but the UserID and Password have to correspond. [Don't return invalid combinations like `foo`/`foo` or `bar`/`bar`] MS Access has a handy FIRST function, which can do this, but I haven't found an equivalent in TSQL.

Also, if it makes a difference, other tables are joined to ACCOUNTS, but this is the only use of LOGINS in the structure.

### Thank you ***very*** much for any assistance.

Quick added info: USERID/PASSWD combinations are unique across the entire LOGIN table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried several of these answers, with limited degrees of success.

I eventually solved the issue by concatenating the USERID & PASSWD fields in the select statement and used the MAX value to return only one.

In other words:

> ```
> SELECT ac.SITE, ac.SUBSET, MAX('user='lo.USERID+'&password='+lo.PASSWD) as IdPwd
> FROM ACCOUNTS ac, LOGIN lo
> WHERE ac.SITE = lo.SITE
> AND ac.SUBSET = lo.SUBSET
> GROUP BY ac.SITE, ac.SUBSET
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier with an autonumber field. You don't really have a good primary key for this table.

```
Select *
From
(
   Select max(id) as MaxID, Site, Subset
   from logins 
   group by site, subset
) UniqueLogins
INNER JOIN logins on UniqueLogins.MaxID = Logins.ID
INNER JOIN Accounts ON logins.site = accounts.site and logins.subset = accounts.subset
```

Edit:
If you can't change schema, you can always dump the records into a temp table with an autonumber, but it may be inefficient if this is being run often, but it will work.

Edit again:
If you went the temp table approach, the code for that is:

```
create table #tmp(
    ID int identity(1,1) primary key
    ,Site <data type>
    ,Subset <data type>
    ,userid <data type>
    ,password <data type>
)

Insert into #tmp(Site 
    ,Subset 
    ,userid 
    ,password )
Select * From logins
--where ???

Select *
From
)
    Select #tmp.* From(
       Select max(id) as MaxID, Site, Subset
       from #tmp 
       group by site, subset
    ) UniqueSites
    INNER JOIN #tmp on #tmp.ID = UniqueSites.MaxID
) UniqueLogins
INNER JOIN Accounts ON UniqueLogins.Site = Accounts.Site and UniqueLogins.Subset = Accounts.Subset

--do whatever else
drop table #tmp
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't set up this table and it's used by other processes so I can't modify it.
But thanks.

Comment: Edited tmp logic to grab out unique userids and passwords. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that may work

```
Select accounts.Site, accounts.Subset, Logins.UserId, Logins.Passwd
From Accounts 
Inner Join
(
    select top 1 Site, Subset, UserId, Passwd
    From Logins logn
    Where Exists
    (
        Select 1
        From Accounts Acc
        where 1=1
        and Acc.Site = Logn.Site
        and Acc.Subset = Logn.Subset
    )
) as OneLoginPerSite
On  Accounts.Site = OneLoginPerSite.Site
and Accounts.Subset = OneLoginPerSite.Subset
```

The Inner SELECT gets you only one Login per Account and then you join this back to the Accounts to get your final result.

Comment: Haven't tried it, but I suspect it will complain that `TOP` in a subquery requires an `ORDER BY`. Access' `FIRST` is basically a hack :) but SQL Server I think doesn't let you say 'oh just order them how you like and pick the first'.

Comment: Just curious, but I guess the 1=1 is just a style that allows you to shuffle and comment out conditions without extra work for the first one?

Comment: @harpo: `1=1` is exactly for the reason you outlined. plus it makes everything more readable and indented.

Answer (score 0):

This may work assuming that USERID/PASSWD combos are unique per SITE/SUBSET combo

```
select a.*, l1.USERID, l1.PASSWD
from ACCOUNTS a
    join LOGINS l1 on a.SITE = l1.SITE and a.SUBSET = l1.SUBSET
where not exists (select * from LOGINS l2 where l1.SITE = l2.SITE and l1.SUBSET = l2.SUBSET and l2.USERID < l1.USERID and l2.PASSWD < l1.PASSWD);
```

also try this to see if it runs faster

```
select a.*, l1.USERID, l1.PASSWD
from ACCOUNTS a
    join LOGINS l1 on a.SITE = l1.SITE and a.SUBSET = l1.SUBSET
    left outer join LOGINS l2 on l1.SITE = l2.SITE and l1.SUBSET = l2.SUBSET and l2.USERID < l1.USERID and l2.PASSWD < l1.PASSWD
where l2.SITE is null;
```

(didn't actually try running these, so a syntax error may have crept in somewhere)

Comment: UserID is not unique, but combinations of UserID & Password *are* unique. [There may be multiple rows with userid `foo`, but only one `foo` with password `bar`

Comment: I've updated the queries to work with USERID/PASSWD combos being unique.